# A multi-symptom affliction

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

"Kindly state your name." The nurse's voice was polite, but qiet.
"I'm sorry, I can't hear you, my hearing's bad."
Being mostly dea*f* was quite frustrating for our patient.


"Please tell me your name and date of birth."
"Pardon, but you really must speak up.."

"Excuse me, are you still there, or did I lose connection," our patient yell over the p*h*one.
Silence again greets *o*ur patint and they check to be sure the phone is still on.

"Really, you must speak up. I am half deaf, and wont hear a thing if you mumble," our patient exclaims.




After another lon*g* pause our patient gives up and turns off the phone.
What a waste of time.. now our patient will just have to go the*r*e in person.




Aft*e*r arriving at the hospital our patient is finally seen by their p*h*ysician.

Our patient will be fine. It's just another case of being affected by ______.
They really should have known bet*t*er, as this isn't the first time its come up.

Now to get back home for some lunch. They were going to make their favo*r*ite food.
By now you should know what it is our paient enjoys consuming, but do you know wat was wrong with them?

You'l need to see this through to the end to see why they were all mixed up.

---

Hint 1

> There are 5 words that lead to a final answer.

Hint 2 (lengths)

> 6, 4, 4, 10, 5

Change:

> I had to modify the misspelled words. This will make the final solution make more sense.

Comment: Hm... Still working on the main question, but the lunch appears to be a rot13(erq ureevat) ;)

Comment: Are the misspellings intentional?

Comment: @YoutRied https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pismg8l57Rs

Comment: Yes, the misspellings are intentional.

Comment: Exactly right, @JesseAmano

Comment: Rot13(vs lbh ebg13 gur vgnyvpvfrq yrggref, lbh trg gur jbeq fhogreshtr)

Comment: There is an unseen <br> that begins the body of the post. All the other breaks are visible without needing to go into the editor.

Comment: For those of you who are dyslexic like me and need spell check to find misspellings, the misspelled words I found are rot13(urnevat'f|urnevat vf, oregu|ovegu, lryf|lryyf, jbag|jba'g, zhzzoyr|zhzoyr, nsrpgrq|nssrpgrq)

Comment: @JesseAmano Because the first letters of each quote spells rot13(xvccre) or just because it seems unrelated?

Comment: @Barker The former (literal) reason; It may or may not be related to the "real" answer, but it seems like it was embedded for fun / as a joke.

Comment: @Barker rot13(V guvax "urnevat'f" vf n inyvq nooerivngvba bs "urnevat vf". Ba gur bgure unaq, "V pna'g urne lbh" vf n pynhfr naq cebonoyl qrfreirf zber chapghngvba guna n pbzzn. Vg orpnzr hapyrne gb zr juvpu reebef jrer vagraqrq naq juvpu ner whfg gur fbegf bs tenzzngvpny/vqvbzngvp zvfgnxrf gung ybgf bs crbcyr bsgra znxr, juvpu pna or n ernyyl tbbq guvat jura gur tbny vf gb fhpprffshyyl uvqr n zrffntr gung bayl fcrpvsvp crbcyr pbhyq be jbhyq qrpbqr, ohg V tnir hc ba fbyivat nsgre n pregnva cbvag.)

Comment: @JesseAmano Valid. I am leaning in the same direction as I feel like I have found at least 4-5 different paths that seem like clues, but I can't get them to really fit anything productive other than the things already pointed out in this comment thread.

Comment: @Barker The missing apostrophe on wont is not part of the puzzle, I'm just lazy.

Comment: @Barker: You missed rot13(bss|bs)